# WordPress link to post links to category (loop)

Tags: categories, redirect

Mindnumbing problem.

1. create a blog post in WP backend
2. select category for post (e.g. podcast)
3. click update

Navigate to blog category page (https://www.bioelectricshield.com/in-the-media/category/podcast)

Click on post (https://www.bioelectricshield.com/in-the-media/emfs-empaths-need-to-know)

URL stays the same in the location bar (url), does not show post, instead redirects to some category (unknown) that lists one blog post. Clicking on THIS post also does not show the post, but redirects to some other URL that shows a category listing of blog posts.

Some posts do work. Not sure why some and not others. Any useful direction is appreciated.

Comment: Impossible to know without the code that is causing this behaviour.

Comment: How would I provide this?

Comment: Well, you're the one who is apparently developing a site... The problem is likely caused by a plugin or theme. Switch each of them on/off, see which one is causing the desired behaviour and once you know, narrow it down to the offensive code.

Comment: Thank you @cjbj. It was an issue with the theme.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem It was theme (Impreza) related (thank you @cjbj).

When the blog post category was created, it created a loop via the theme:

incorrect:
[image: incorrect settings]

correct:
[image: correct settings]